# Formatting timespan to input

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How do i format a timespan to an input type time field in mvc core using tag helpers?

i have tried the following:

```
<input asp-for="ScoreCard.StartTime" type="time" value="@string.Format("{0:hh:mm}", Model.ScoreCard.StartTime)" class="form-control">
```

But this results in the following compilation error:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized(TimeSpan value,
>   string format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi)

Comment: I guess it should be `HH:mm`, not `hh:mm`. Another side question - do you really need this `string.Format`? Why not `Model.ScoreCard.StartTime.ToString("HH:mm")`?

Comment: That resulted in the same error. 
As for string.format vs .tostring when i was learning about formatting string.format was consistently the answer the polled the most. Is there a reason now to use one over other?

Answer (score 3):

I was using an incorrect format.
The correct one is:

```
<input asp-for="ScoreCard.StartTime" type="time" value="@string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm}", Model.ScoreCard.StartTime)" class="form-control">
```